# Using a script to find blanks in two columns and filling the blanks with any content above the blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, autofill

I'm trying to create a macro in Google Sheets for a daily function that I do in Excel. The problem I'm having is that Google Sheets lacks a function that Excel has. That function being the ability to find all blanks and fill in those blanks with values in above fields. I imagine this can be done with a script, but I've been unsuccessful in my attempts.

The sheet I'm using is called `Research Macro` and I need to run this script at the end of a macro to check columns A:B for blanks, and either insert a formula to populate the value above said blank (unless that cell is a blank, then I would need the above value, etc.) or just insert the value itself.

Comment: This is a working script that solves my problem.

function fill() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Research Macro');
  const rng = sh.getRange('A1:B' + sh.getLastRow());
  rng.setValues(
    rng.getValues().map(function(e, i, a) {
      return e[0] ? e : ((a[i] = a[i <= 0 ? 0 : i - 1]), a[i]);
    })
  );
}

Answer (score 2):

I think the Excel function you refer to is available in Sheets, with Find and replace:

Select relevant range (but format range as Plain text first) and Find `^`, Replace with:

```
=offset(indirect(address(Row(),Column(),4)),-1,0)
```

with the first three options ticked.

Comment: This works perfectly. I wasn't aware of the functionality of Find and Replace in Google sheets. I'm certain I'll use this often going forward. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon. While it's true that it populated the data as needed, the Find and Replace function can't be placed into a macro. If i'm going to do this outside of excel, i need it to be justified.